# Bug or feature? If statement inside double integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

(taken from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592901/bug-or-feature-if-statement-inside-double-integrals)

Generally speaking,

$$ \int_c^a f(x) dx = \int_c^{a-b} f(x) dx + \int_{a-b}^a f(x) dx$$

However, consider the following Mathematica code:

```
h[x_] := If[0 <= x <= 1, 1, 0]
i[y_] := If[0 <= y <= 1, 1, 0]
a = 1
b = 1/2

Integrate[Integrate[i[y], {y, x + 1/2, 1}], {x, 1/4, a}]
```

Which yields $-(3/32)$.

But splitting up:

```
Integrate[Integrate[i[y], {y, x + 1/2, 1}], {x, 1/4, a - b}]
```

yielding $1/32$

```
Integrate[Integrate[i[y], {y, x + 1/2, 1}], {x, a - b, a}]
```

yielding $0$

One can easily establish that the correct solution is indeed the sum of the two sub-integrals $1/32 + 0 = 1/32$, so base-integral $-3/32$ is wrong.

Am I invoking the functions in a wrong way? Should I not use If statements inside integrals?

Comment: An actual (not nested) double integral `Integrate[ i[y] h[x] , {x, 1/4, 1} ,  {y, x + 1/2, 1} ]` gives the correct result.  Why the nested result is wrong is a bit puzzling.

Comment: you can see the `-3/32` result comes from the inner integral incorrectly evaluating to `(1/2-x)` as if `0<=y<=1` independent of `x`.

Comment: *Should I not use If statements inside integrals?* Generally, that shouldn't be a problem. The `Integrate` help page has a few examples using `If` or `Boole`.

Comment: The inner integral seems to cause trouble when in the nested form. If given suitable assumptions on the whereabouts of `x` it is much better. `Integrate[
Integrate[i[y], {y, x + 1/2, 1}, Assumptions -> 1/4 < x < a], {x, 
  1/4, a}]

Out[750]= 1/32`

Comment: @march My initial impression, that you found a bug, was from lack of sufficient scepticism. What happened is you reversed the condition and value in the `Piecewise` integrand.

Comment: While one might get reasonable results with iterated integrals and `If``-based integrands, `Piecewise` and `Boole` tend to be the more reliable tools (they are "math" as opposed to "procedural programming" constructs). In this case we get a valid result, and a useful warning, by using a `Piecewise` integrand: `Integrate[Integrate[Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= y <= 1}}], {y, x + 1/2, 1}], {x, 1/4, a}]

During evaluation of In[754]:= Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {1,1/2+x} are real. Adding assumptions may help. >>

Out[754]= 1/32`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. Oh. Right. Well, good thing, then! I think the `Piecewise` solution actually works then.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Beware. Lack of skepticism was [documented as the cause of disappearance of entire armies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Red_Sea)

Comment: @Dr.Belisarius And there is [this gem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waist_Deep_in_the_Big_Muddy) as well; see also [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24VOo7-ctKU), or maybe it's hear also.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Much more authoritative and politically correct :)